# How to handle Negative test cases in playwright

Tags: playwright

Say example for Login case, how to handle p/w / username error msg thrown properly on providing invalid input. As a newbie, I need to look into examples. Kindly share

```js
const { webkit } = require("playwright");
(async () => {
  const browser = await webkit.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
  await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login");

  await page.click("button.s-btn__google");

  await page.fill('input[type="email"]', process.env.GOOGLE_USER);
  await page.click("#identifierNext");

  await page.fill('input[type="password"]', process.env.GOOGLE_PWD);
  await page.click("#passwordNext");

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: You can assert that certain element contains an 'invalid password' text

Comment: In my case , I was trying to verify error message on creating an event without name but my test case got failed .Here i was trying to assert error msg text content .Error shown like below

 FAIL   browser: chromium  test.js
  ● Event Detail › Create Event for testing

    **Object**